# Is there any practical difference between \n and \n$

Tags: regex

Is there any practical difference between this regular expressions?

```
\n

\n$
```

I am thinking, could the second one match the end of line and then the end of file?

Consider the UNIX world were the end of line is always \n.

Comment: `"\nA"` doesn't match the second regex.

Comment: Some regex engines have options for multi-line matching.

Answer (score 1):

If `m` *multiline*  mode is set, `\n$` means a `\n` which is followed by another `\n` (OS based) since `$` asserts position before following newline character. i.e. two blank lines in a row. `\n` alone matches every occurrence of newline characters.

> I am thinking, could the second one match the end of line and then the
>   end of file?

By default `$` matches end of input string (or EOF). In some flavors it acts as `\Z`: match end of input string preceded by an optional newline character.

Comment: "`$` asserts position before a newline character (if multiline mode is set)" - this is wrong.

Comment: If you mean wrong by the word *before*, that's my expression to show `$\n`

Comment: Hence *if multiline mode is set* @Aran-Fey

Comment: @Aran-Fey `$` never matches a newline.

Comment: @melpomene Eh, you know what I meant. I phrased it correctly in my first sentence.

Comment: Moved it to beginning. @Aran-Fey

Comment: @Aran-Fey No, I don't know what you meant (especially the *one special case*?).

Comment: @revo Your answer suggests `"\n" =~ /\n$/m` does not match (because there are not two newlines in a row), but it does.

Comment: @melpomene The special case I was referring to is a newline right before the end of the string. Anyway, I guess I should clean up the mess I made under revo's answer, since I was wrong and the comments are no longer relevant at all.